# Best way to sum >=2 columns of a panda data frame into a single/scalar value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I must sum, into a single number, all the values contained in two or more columns of a pandas dataframe.
The sum must not include all numeric columns in the dataframe.
I can only do it like shown below, which looks awkward to me, this is to ask if there is a better way.

*[Edit after answer]:*  In particular I wonder if I can avoid the ..sum().sum() and list the columns to be summed rather than those to ignore.

```
import pandas as pd

GAINS, LOSSES, IGNORE = 'gains', 'losses', 'ignore'

df = pd.DataFrame({
    GAINS : [11, 12],
    LOSSES: [-1, -2],
    IGNORE : [88, 99]
    })

total = df[[GAINS, LOSSES]].sum().sum()
print(total)

20
```

Comment: It looks fine to me, you can convert to numpy: `df[[GAIN, LOSSES]].to_numpy().sum()` but it's even more awkward?

Comment: What you're asking to do is to take the sum of a sum.  Why do you find the notation awkward?  In Pandas, the columns are very often unrelated data types, so there aren't a lot of "whole frame" operations.  That's very different from Numpy, where an array is always a single data type.

Comment: @QuangHoang your comment seems to confirm that it is not possible to do it in a single  shot, so it is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
In [610]: df[df.columns.difference(['ignore'])].sum().sum()
Out[610]: 20
```

###### EDIT after OP's comment:

```
In [616]: df[df.columns.difference(['ignore'])].values.sum()
Out[616]: 20

OR

In [617]: df[df.columns.difference(['ignore'])].to_numpy().sum()
Out[617]: 20
```